# Issue with ajax login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax login system on a website. username and password submitting using post method. but randomly username and password showing in URL with a query string like http://www.example.com?username=abc&pass=123456. 
why this is happening ? below is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $body = $('body'),
        $content = $('#content'),
        $form = $content.find('#loginform'); 
        $("input .logingform").uniform(); 
        $form.wl_Form({
            status:false,
            onBeforeSubmit: function(data){
                $form.wl_Form('set','sent',false);
                if(data.username || data.password){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: $form.attr('action'),
                        data: 'username=' + data.username + '&password=' + data.password + '&rememberme=' + data.rememberme + '',
                        success: function(msg) {

                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    $.wl_Alert('Please provide something!','info','#content');
                }
                return false;

            }                             
        }); 
});
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Yes Please show you code

Comment: Ross please check code

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $body = $('body'),
    $content = $('#content'),
    $form = $content.find('#loginform'); 
    $("input .logingform").uniform(); 
    $form.wl_Form({
        status:false,
        onBeforeSubmit: function(data){
            $form.wl_Form('set','sent',false);
            if(data.username || data.password){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: $form.attr('action'),
                    data: {username:data.username,password:data.password,remermberme:data.rememberme},
                    success: function(msg) {

                    }
                });
            }else{
                $.wl_Alert('Please provide something!','info','#content');
            }
            return false;

        }                             
    }); 
});
```

Change Your Data section under ajax call

Comment: why this is happening ?

Comment: Becuase you are using & character which denotes granular Chunk of data

Comment: ok but old code and your new do the same thing on the server. mean data parameter

Answer (score 1):

Another Method is to remove Query String Using Jquery Like this:-

```
   $(function(){
      history.replaceState({}, "", location.href.split("?")[0]);
   });
```